# Haskell regex, a section must be enclosed in parentheses thus

Tags: regex, haskell

I'm working from [this text](https://learning.oreilly.com/library/view/practical-web-development/9781484237397/html/461381_1_En_2_Chapter.xhtml), where I see the example:

```
> gsub [re|\d+|] "x" "1 and 2 and 3" :: Text -- 7
"x and x and x"
```

Similarly, I'd like to use gsub to replace /non/ digits with nulls, but what seemed like a pretty straightforward translation fails:

```
Prelude Text.Regex.Posix> gsub [re|\D+|] "" "$57.72" :: Float

<interactive>:14:7: error:
    A section must be enclosed in parentheses thus: (re |\ D +|)
```

Then I notice, even the original example fails for me with the same error:

```
Prelude Text.Regex.Posix Data.Text> gsub [re|\d+|] "x" "1 and 2 and 3" :: Text

<interactive>:17:7: error:
    A section must be enclosed in parentheses thus: (re |\ d +|)
```

Why is the interpreter telling me to do something different from what works in this example and how do I get some kind of text substitution with regex to work?

Comment: Are you using the `QuasiQuotes` extension?

Comment: The parser seems to think you are using a `+|` operator with no right operand.

Answer (score 0):

If you turn on the `QuasiQuotes` language extension, GHC will parse `[re|\d+|]` differently, as the string `\d+` passed to the quasi-quoter `re`. BTW I'm not sure you have the right imports, since [the `re` quasi-quoter seems to come from `pcre-heavy`'s `Text.Regex.PCRE.Heavy` module](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/pcre-heavy-1.0.0.2/docs/Text-Regex-PCRE-Heavy.html#g:4).

So the below should work from GHCi:

```
Prelude Data.Text> :set -XQuasiQuotes
Prelude Data.Text> import Text.Regex.PCRE.Heavy
Prelude Data.Text Text.Regex.PCRE.Heavy> gsub [re|\d+|] "x" "1 and 2 and 3" :: Text
```